# Problem while updating :(

Tags: 12.04, jre

[image: Error - please explain]

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. And I recently installed Open JDK from the Software Center and also the Iced Tea Plugin. From that time, whenever I install any updates or packages, this error pops up. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://twiki.grid.iu.edu/bin/view/Documentation/Release3/KnownProblems#Java_upgrade

Apparently, you can ignore this error.

Comment: It comes every time I do some installation!